# AlertController - Ion-icon with the text in the buttons

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is that possible to display a ion-icon in the button with the text in AlertController? I tried below code but no luck.

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Confirmation',
      message: 'This page is going to refresh?',
      cssClass: 'customCss',
      enableBackdropDismiss: false,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: `<ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon> Refresh`,
          cssClass: 'refresh-button',
          handler: (data: any) => {         
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          cssClass: 'cancel-button',
          handler: (data: any) => {          

          }
        }

      ]
    });
    alert.present();
```

It will display the html as text in the button. Is there any other way to achieve this with out using Modal.

Thanks

Comment: If it fits your UI you could also use a [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/) instead.

Comment: It is not possible with alert controller, so instead used Modal to achieve this.